# Weird display issue with .svg

Tags: css, svg

I'm getting a really strange issue when using svg's on my site, see https://i.stack.imgur.com/2KgR4.png. The svg that I want displayed is just the arrow icon, but the rest of the characters in the svg set (along with a box for some reason) are also showing up very tiny to the left. Check out the lists on http://camilleblock.com/critter/features/typography/

Has anyone else run into this issue, if so how did you fix it?

Comment: Can you put up a fiddle with the relevant code highlighting the issue for people to play with.

Comment: Here it is http://jsfiddle.net/NYBPJ/